# Entity Framework - Creating a strongly typed projection in the designer

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a strongly typed projection entity "ProjectedPersons" via the designer in the Entity Framework.

I am using POCO classes and have seperated them out into seperate projects.

I keep getting an error:

error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - ProjectedPersons.

How can I remove this error. I only want to use the entity for projections not mapping to the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the object only for projections - I would recommend creating it as a complex type instead.  You get much of the same features without a lot of the contextual overhead that is inherent to an entity.  I believe an entity is fully expecting to be mapped to a database feature in some respect - hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define projection in designer you must use [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) (projection query defined directly in the designer and mapped to the new readonly entity) - that is the feature which must be manually defined directly in XML (MSL part) not in the designer. Otherwise you must do projection manually in Linq query. For linq query you don't need to create entity in the designer. You can use any class which is not mapped in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The QueryView was the solution. I found a helpful example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336312.aspx